# How to use foreach loop in codeigniter email send

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I want to send email in codeigniter controller. I have used foreach loop in body for multiple attachment. but it's not working. give me some suggestion
here is my controller function.

```
function emailSend($ship_item_data{

    //$link =   base_url();                 
    $email ="abc.develop01@gmail.com";
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($email, 'GHL Sports'); 
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Sold items detail'); 
    $msg='<html>
        <head>
        <title>Sold item</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Dear GHL Sports Client.
        <p>This items heas been sold.</p><ul>';

        foreach($ship_item_data as $data){

            $item   =   $data['image_name'];
            $this->email->attach("sold/".$item);
            $msg .= '<li>'. $item .'</li>';

        }

        $msg .='</u>
            Please do reply to this email as it will not be monitored.
        </body>
            </html>';

    $this->email->message($msg); 
    //$link =   base_url();                         
    //$this->email->attach("sold/1.jpg");
     //Send mail 
    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo "email send successfully";
    }else{
        echo "email not send";  
    }
```

I have also include email library in constructor.

```
$this->load->helper('path');
$this->load->library('email');
```

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090421/codeigniter-attaching-2-files-to-email-that-have-been-uploaded-from-user-form

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **$this->email->clear(TRUE);** to clean out the variables set within the loop.